# Debugging code that is working fine on computer but not on SPOJ

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

This code is working fine on my computer but SPJ tells me that it's got a segmentation fault. Can you please help me debug it?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i, arr[5];
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Enter number between 0 to 99 \n";
        cin >> arr[i]        
    }

    while (arr[j] != 42) { 
        cout << arr[j] << "\n";
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because you make the code for something like SPOJ doesn't mean you shouldn't format it properly.

Comment: As for the problem, think about what would happen if there is no value `42` in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop:

```
while (arr[j] != 42) { 
  cout << arr[j] << "\n";
  j++;
}
```

Will only exit if someone entered 42. If they didn't then `j` will be incremented to 5 and beyond, which means you'll attempt to access an array index that doesn't exist, as `arr` is only 5 elements long.

One fix would be to check `j` as you're iterating the items:

```
while (j<5 && arr[j] != 42) { 
  cout << arr[j] << "\n";
  j++;
}
```